# Change default terminal 19.04

Tags: command-line, 19.04

I'd like to use hyper instead of tilix, I've tried this :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

but this does not work, and I can't find why ubuntu is still using tilix when I use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

here is the output i get  :

```
Il existe 3 choix pour l'alternative x-terminal-emulator (qui fournit /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator).

  Sélection   Chemin                           Priorité  État
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /opt/Hyper/hyper                  50        mode automatique
* 1            /opt/Hyper/hyper                  50        mode manuel
  2            /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper   40        mode manuel
  3            /usr/bin/tilix.wrapper            30        mode manuel
Appuyez sur <Entrée> pour conserver la valeur par défaut[*] ou choisissez le numéro sélectionné :1
```

And then i retry ctrl+alt+t but tilix show up again...
I installed Hyper with the deb package from their website.

Comment: What message do you get when running the above-mentioned command? Did you manually configure the keyboard shortcut to open tilix?

Comment: whats the output when you run that cmd

Comment: How did you install hyper? Does it provide x-terminal-emulator? FYI: X Terminal emulator is a virtual package. Not all  terminals provide X terminal emulator.

Comment: Sorry guys it's a bit late but i managed to fix it haha